# SQL Server trigger based on Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger in SQL Server 2017 that will fire on `INSERT` and work off the `CreatedDate` column of my table.

The `CreatedDate` is of this format: `2017-09-21 07:15:59.883`

What I want to do is check the time of the `CreatedDate` column and if it is between 7 and 8 I need to insert a value into a `Notes` column, if it is between 15 and 16 I need to insert another, if it is between 23 and 24 I need to insert another.

I am particularly stuck at the `WHERE` clause that I need to check the hour for. Not sure how to formulate this.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: If you provide your code (as in - what you already have, but which isn't working) then it is more likely that the answers will match your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your CreatedDate is datetime and not string

use datepart to checks for createdate hour and update the Notes column accordingly

```
UPDATE t
SET    Notes = 'a value'
FROM   inserted i
       INNER JOIN mytable t ON i.pk = t.pk
WHERE  datepart(hour, CreateDate) in (7, 8)
```

EDIT :

```
UPDATE t
SET    Notes = case when datepart(hour, CreateDate) in ( 7,  8) then 'a value'
                    when datepart(hour, CreateDate) in (15, 16) then 'another value'
                    end
FROM   inserted i
       INNER JOIN mytable t ON i.pk = t.pk
WHERE  datepart(hour, CreateDate) in (7, 8, 15, 16)
```

Comment: upvoted and if CreateDate is a validate date string, that is fine

Comment: How would I get this into the CASE WHEN context for the three different hours?

Comment: are you updating the same `Notes` column or different column ?

Comment: Same Notes column with one of three different values based on hour value

Comment: updated the query

Comment: Thanks I think this will do it

Comment: Except that the `in()` construct is unnecessary in the context of what was originally asked for. A time between 7:00 and 8:00 will always have an hour == 7. Similarly for a time between 15:00 and 16:00, or a time between 23:00 and 00:00.

Answer (score 1):

See [datepart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)

```
    where case  when DATEPART ( HOUR, datetimeField )  =7  then someValue
          case  when DATEPART ( HOUR, datetimeField )  =15 then SomeOtherValue
          case  when DATEPART ( HOUR, datetimeField )  =23 then AnotherDiffetentValue
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEPART`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

and `CASE`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql